# Grant to execute the stored function without granting to use objects inside the function

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

Here is a simple test:

```
nd@postgres=# create table t(i serial primary key, x text);
nd@postgres=# create function t_get(p_x in text = null) returns setof t language sql as $$ select * from t where i % 2 = 0 and p_x is null or x ilike p_x $$;
nd@postgres=# insert into t(x) select generate_series(1,10,2);
nd@postgres=# select * from t_get();
╔═══╤═══╗
║ i │ x ║
╠═══╪═══╣
║ 2 │ 3 ║
║ 4 │ 7 ║
╚═══╧═══╝
```

So far so good as said.

However my goal is to grant to the regular user the access to functions without access to tables used:

```
nd@postgres=# create role testrole with login password '111';
nd@postgres=# grant execute on function t_get(text) to testrole;
nd@postgres=# set role testrole;
nd@postgres=> select * from t_get();
ERROR:  permission denied for relation t
CONTEXT:  SQL function "t_get" statement 1
```

PostgreSQL positioned as OOP database as I know and encapsulation is one of the three whales of the OOP.

So my question is: Is it possible to hide the actual table behind the getter/setter functions in PostgreSQL? If yes - how?

Comment: You need to define the function with `SECURITY DEFINER` and create it using a user that is allowed to access the tables.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks, `alter function t_get(text) security definer;` solves the problem. I definitely should to read the doc more attentively. Can you post the answer that I will be able to accept it?